# dpkg-deb subprocess killed by signal (Broken pipe) in Boot upgrade

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, dpkg

Hi I want to upgrade my app but I get this error :

[image]

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic but it is not installed
 linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-48-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic but it is not installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-48-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After that, I ran the following command as suggested, but I got the arrow again:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

[image]

```
...
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 378143 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-5.15.0-48-generic_5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.15.0-48-generic (5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-5.15.0-48-generic_5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-5.15.0-48-generic' to '/boot/System.map-5.15.0-48-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic_5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic (5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic_5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-48-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-48-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken p
ipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-5.15.0-48-generic_5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic_5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Now what should I do to get rid of this problem?
I should add that my boot space is completely full (260MB).
Im in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: If you have no free space on the drive or in a particular partition you can not do anything till you free up some space. You may also want to investigate why that space is full.

Comment: Never run out of boot space. You probably need to fix this, so you don't encounter the same problem in the future.